# React Router 4 points to primary domain not subfolder

Tags: javascript, react-router

I have an app which is within a sub folder of my primary domain. So Test.com is my domain and my app is in a folder called 'Player' in that domain i.e Test.com/player.

The problem is React Router points to Test.com when it needs to point to Test.com/player.

The other issue is my index file is in a folder called 'public'.

How do I do this in React Router 4/htacess?

Thanks

App

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, hashHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter history={hashHistory}>
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route render={() => {
              return <h1>Not Found!</h1>
            }} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("main"));
```

Webpack

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    filename: "./app/app.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "./app/build/bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ["es2015", "react"]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 5000,
    contentBase: "./public",
    historyApiFallback: true,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to React Router Docs, BrowserRouter has

> basename: string The base URL for all locations. If your app is served
>   from a sub-directory on your server, you’ll want to set this to the
>   sub-directory. A properly formatted basename should have a leading
>   slash, but no trailing slash.

you can use

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter history={hashHistory} basename="/player">
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route render={() => {
              return <h1>Not Found!</h1>
            }} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

You also need those properties on your webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
   entry : 'your entry',
   output : {
      path : 'your path',
      filename : 'your filename',
      publicPath : '/' //ADD THIS LINE (either / or /player will work)
   },
   devServer : {
      historyApiFallback : true // ADD THIS LINE
   }
}
```

Comment: Home component works and on page refresh works, but when i click to go to my about page or contact page it loads initially but on page refresh i just get 404.

Comment: @JoeConsterdine I have edited my answer, I hope those changes help you